How can I modify mathfunction textstyle?
One can define a new mathfunctions with
\definemathfunction[name][opts]

However, I haven't found a way to change the style of the attached text.
Suppose I want to define a new mathfunction called testfunc to which I want to ensure that the attached text is always upright or perhaps fraktur or whatever. Can I do this?
I know I can just define a macro to achieve it
\definemathfunction[testfunc]
\define[1]{\Testfunc}{\testfunc{\mathupright{#1}}}

but doesn't that defeat the whole purpose?

You can play with this:
\definemathtext
  [mathtextss]
  [mathtext]
  [style=\ss\bf]

\setupmathfunctions
  [style=\mathtextss]

\definemathfunction[Abc]
\definemathfunction[Def]
\definemathfunction[Ghi]

\setupmathfunction
  [Def]
  [style=\mathtextsl]

\setupmathfunction
  [Ghi]
  [style=\mathfrak]

\startTEXpage[offset=1TS]

\m {\Abc (x) + \Def (y) + \Ghi (z) + \sin(x)}

\stopTEXpage



Great. Thanks to you pointing out \setupmathfunction I was able to discover this manual.
